# Applying blur using RenderScript in Android creates weird output

Tags: java, android, renderscript

I'm attempting to apply a blur to an image using the RenderScript class. Here is the code I use (where this.image is the original Bitmap)

```
    Bitmap inputImage = this.image;
    int height = inputImage.getHeight();
    int width = inputImage.getWidth();
    Bitmap blurredImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(context);
    ScriptIntrinsicBlur theIntrinsic = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));
    Allocation tmpIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, inputImage);
    Allocation tmpOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, blurredImage);
    theIntrinsic.setRadius(25.f);
    theIntrinsic.setInput(tmpIn);
    theIntrinsic.forEach(tmpOut);
    tmpOut.copyTo(blurredImage);

    this.image = blurredImage;
    return true;
```

This is the input and output from the function
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2d9DU.jpg

For some reason, it appears to double the image and then only keep the green channel or something. Fidling around with the blur radius doesn't work, and I can't find anything wrong with my code (which was copied from a working example)

Comment: What format is the input bitmap?  This almost looks as if the input is 16bit.  The RS blur only supports 8 bit per channel bitmaps.

Comment: Ever find out what was wrong? @deepCover

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error and found out what was causing it, i know it's a question from 2 years ago but still for the ones who come up with same problem.

The problem was the images that i've been using is RGB_565 formatted and because Renderscript blurring is not getting enough specifications from RGB_565 images it results outputs be like this.

I was using UniversalImageLoader with RGB_565 configuration to reduce memory usage and having blur effect when necessary on downloaded images, and when i remove that configuration to use as default ARGB_8888 format, everything was just fine!

**Sum up: Don't use RGB_565 while having renderscript blur, use ARGB_8888 instead.**